# C# Setting image to multiple controls is slow

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to clone the game "Minesweeper" in c#.

When I create a field, I want the background of the button control to be the same as in the original game "Minesweeper".

However, when I create my field and I add all the images it takes at least 1-5 seconds to completely load the field.

Code for creating the field:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fieldsize; i++)
{
      for (int j = 0; j < fieldsize; j++)
      {
          panel1.controls.add(new Button(){backgroundimage = properties.resources.field})
      }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is that all the code? You're not actually using `i` and `j` anywhere?

Comment: Use a single image this way `var img = Properties.Resources.SomeImage` and then assign img to `BackGroupnImage` property of buttons. If using `Properties.Resources.SomeImage` it will return a new image each time you read from resource. Also if you are using `TableLayoutPanel`/`FlowLayoutPanel` frist call `SuspendLayout` and after finishing adding controls, call `ResumeLayout(true)`.